# Bootstrap two column layout misaligned in firefox & ie

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

The layout for this site is working correctly in Chrome - however on both the latest versions of IE and Firefox some page columns are misaligned. 
Example of misaligned page: http://itsworldcongress2016.com/home/invitation

The strangest thing is that the same bootstrap column code is used on the homepage and it renders consistently across all three browsers. 
Correct page alignment: http://itsworldcongress2016.com/

Originally I thought that it might be an issue with one of the margin classes that has been applied to the two columns, but removal of this didn't fix the issue.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: now that's  weird issue the code looks perfectly fine :P but for some reason the column is not aligned left. Just checked one of my websites in same browser with bootstrap 3 and it fine there

Comment: this seems to be a bug in firefox try upgrading your bootstrap css to latest version 3.2 as i tested that in same browser and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this renders differently in different browsers, or across different pages, but it's related to `h1.hidden-xs`.

Adding this to main.css appears to resolve the issue:

```
h1.hidden-xs {
    margin:0;
}
```

There are other ways to fix this, surely (for example, changing `font-size` on that h1 does it too). Another way might integrate better with your markup or styles or might be generally better, but this way works.